# trouble with gem install gsl in fedora 17

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora, gsl

I have Fedora 17 and I have the following installed:

```
    ruby-1.9.3.327-19.fc17.x86_64 
    rubygems-1.8.24-1.fc17.noarch 
    gsl-1.15-4.fc17.x86_64 
    gsl-devel-1.15-4.fc17.x86_64
```

I run

```
$ gem install gsl
```

trying to get ruby/gsl.

I get the result

```
ERROR: Error installing gsl: 
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

plus a big long output. Any suggestions as to what I may be missing?

Any suggestions as to what to do to get gem install gsl to work?

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on without log. Could you run `gsl-config`?

Comment: You know what the big log output is for? Pasting here.

Comment: Seems like gsl gem is outdated and was built for gsl 1.4.x. So you need to downgrade gsl lib to 1.4.x or refactor gsl gem to 1.5.x

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev How would I go about downgrading? And how do I run <code>gsl-config</code>

Comment: @tadman I can't find any way to post this code, it tells me it is wrongly formatted code. Google isn't helping

Comment: Well, you should uninstall installed rpms gsl and gsl-devel, then download 1.14.x version from here: [link](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.14.tar.gz) (Actially, I was wrong with versions in my prev post, you should read 1.14 and 1.15 where it's 1.4 and 1.5). Well, than you untar downloaded arch and compile & install it: `./config; make; sudo make install`. Than install gsl gem `gem install gsm`. At least this works for me (on OSX though)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev will I need a gsl-devel for the same version?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I did what you said and I open irb and try <code>require "GSL"</code> and get the following error

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev  <code>LoadError: cannot load such file -- GSL
        from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
<code>

Comment: It means you didn't install this gem. What do you get when run `gsl-config --version`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I get 1.14

Comment: Well, seems like this gem is not installed. To be sure the gem was installed, last try `sudo gem install gsl` and tell us what output is.

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
.....
ERROR:  Error installing gsl:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking gsl version... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:237:in `rescue in <main>': Check GSL>=0.9.4 is installed, and the command "gsl-config" is in search path. (RuntimeError)

Comment: from extconf.rb:138:in `<main>'
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/gsl-1.14.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/gsl-1.14.7/ext/gem_make.out

Comment: Seems like it (gem installator) couldn't find gsl lib properly. Could you send me `mkmf.log` and `gem_make.out` to `yanfilofyev (at) gmail . com address`? They are somewhere in `/usr/local/share/gems/gems/gsl-1.14.7/...` location

Comment: I've been through that whole folder and can't find them. Any idea why it may not have been made?